# How do I use QueryOverride in CQWP when deploying web part instance using Elements.xml?

Tags: 2010, web-part, content-query-web-part, elements-xml

I need to use the CQWP with more than three filters, hence I'm going to use the QueryOverride with a CAML query like [described here](http://sharepointroot.com/2011/06/03/cqwp-with-more-than-three-filters/). I can't get this to work when deploying the web part instance using Elements.xml i.e. AllUsersWebPart and CDATA.

The way I did it with normal filters was like the following (from Elements.xml)

```
<AllUsersWebPart ID="FindingsCQWP" WebPartZoneID="Middle" WebPartOrder="1" >
          <![CDATA[
            <webParts>
              <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
                <metaData>
                  <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
                  <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
                </metaData>
                <data>
                  <properties>
                    <property name="GroupBy" type="string" />
                    <property name="FilterValue2" type="string">Draft</property>
                    ... and so forth...
```

However [QueryOverride requires using CDATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa981241.aspx) as well. The problem is that I dont' think 'nested' CDATA elements are allowed. I've tried [HTML encoding](http://smanjunath.wordpress.com/2010/09/05/cdata-in-cewp/) the CAML as a workaround/approach, but to no avail.

What is the solution here? I guess I could write some feature receiver code, but I'd like to avoid that if I can.

Comment: Have you considered extending the CQWP and set the query through code?

Comment: That seems to me like too much work, and if I'm going to code an easier approach is to set the property in the feature receiver code.

Comment: It is more work, true, but at least it would work :)  
I guess the feature event receiver approach could be discussed, in that case even using PS directly would be just as simple, or a console app

Comment: Well, I disagree that using PS or console app is just as simple. Sure, the code is much the same, but at least using a feature receiver the solution will automatically apply the change, while PS/console would need to be manually run after deploy.

Comment: It depends on your use case, but the point was that you would not need a deploy. Although I guess this is beside the point of your question

Comment: Yeah, for updating something in use I can def. see your approach feasible! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Andrey's response pinpointed me to the answer of this question. The Query needs to be Encoded. I tried that in my initial approach, but I must have missed something.

I had this CAML that I wanted to have in my QueryOverride

```
<Where>
  <And>
     <And>
        <Or>
           <Eq>
              <FieldRef Name='Status' />
              <Value Type='Choice'>Not Started</Value>
           </Eq>
           <Eq>
              <FieldRef Name='Status' />
              <Value Type='Choice'>Not Closed</Value>
           </Eq>
        </Or>
        <Leq>
           <FieldRef Name='TargetImplDate' />
           <Value Type='DateTime'>
              <Today />
           </Value>
        </Leq>
     </And>
     <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='Category' />
        <Value Type='Choice'></Value>
     </Eq>
  </And>
</Where>
<OrderBy>
  <FieldRef Name='ProcessChoice' />
  <FieldRef Name='TargetImplDate' />
</OrderBy>
```

Using CDATA when I added the web part to the web part gallery, and adding it to the page and exporting it afterwards got the result

```
<property name="QueryOverride" type="string">&lt;Where&gt;&lt;And&gt;&lt;And&gt;&lt;Or&gt;&lt;Eq&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name='Status' /&gt;&lt;Value Type='Choice'&gt;Not Started&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Eq&gt;&lt;Eq&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name='Status' /&gt;&lt;Value Type='Choice'&gt;Not Closed&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Eq&gt;&lt;/Or&gt;&lt;Leq&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name='TargetImplDate' /&gt;&lt;Value Type='DateTime'&gt;&lt;Today /&gt;&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Leq&gt;&lt;/And&gt;&lt;Eq&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name='Category' /&gt;&lt;Value Type='Choice'&gt;&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Eq&gt;&lt;/And&gt;&lt;/Where&gt;&lt;OrderBy&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name='ProcessChoice' /&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name='TargetImplDate' /&gt;&lt;/OrderBy&gt;</property>
```

which worked as expected. Thanks @Andrey

Answer (score 1):

Kind of workaround, but still: deploy CQWP without this property to a page, set the property programmatically, and then export webpart to *.webpart* file.

I anticipate some kind of double HTML encoding nightmare like as a result.

P.S. Not tested.

P.S.S. If you will not be able to export the webpart from browser, try using programmatic approach ([ExportWebPart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.splimitedwebpartmanager.exportwebpart.aspx) method of SPLimitedWebPartManager).

Comment: Good idea. I used CDATA when the web part was deployed to the web part gallery, added it to the page and lo and behold it worked. The output was as you guessed some HTML encoding version of the string. It looks just like what I tried earlier, but I must have missed something, or maybe I had some encoding errors. I'll add a separate answer, as this is not really the answer to the question (but a good tip for getting there!)

Answer (score -1):

Please keep in mind that

```
<where> or &lt;Where&gt;
```

tag should go on the same line with

```
<property name="QueryOverride" type="string">
```

like this

```
 <property name="QueryOverride" type="string">&lt;Where&gt;
        &lt;Or&gt;
          &lt;Eq&gt;
            &lt;FieldRef Name="AssignedTo"/&gt;
            &lt;Value Type="User"&gt;
              &lt;UserID/&gt;
            &lt;/Value&gt;
          &lt;/Eq&gt;
          &lt;Membership Type="CurrentUserGroups"&gt;
            &lt;FieldRef Name="AssignedTo"/&gt;
          &lt;/Membership&gt;
        &lt;/Or&gt;
      &lt;/Where&gt;</property>
```

and NOT like this

```
 <property name="QueryOverride" type="string">
     &lt;Where&gt;
        &lt;Or&gt;
          &lt;Eq&gt;
            &lt;FieldRef Name="AssignedTo"/&gt;
            &lt;Value Type="User"&gt;
              &lt;UserID/&gt;
            &lt;/Value&gt;
          &lt;/Eq&gt;
          &lt;Membership Type="CurrentUserGroups"&gt;
            &lt;FieldRef Name="AssignedTo"/&gt;
          &lt;/Membership&gt;
        &lt;/Or&gt;
      &lt;/Where&gt;
</property>
```